# Action and state shown on console but undefined on application with React hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I am trying to create an application that read from an API and print on the screen the list of itens but is not working.

I did a codesandbox here with a Fake API: https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-wright-on220 and I explain below the problem going though the code

First I have created my store on index.js

```
const store = createStore(reducer, applyMiddleware(...middleware));

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact component={Dashboard} />
        <Route component={NoMatchRoute} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
};
```

I have created my state on metrics.js

```
 export type MetricState = {
  metrics: IMetric[];
};
```

And finally on Dashboard.tsx I print on the screen bu updating the state by doing an api call with 'fetchMetrics':

```
const catalog = useSelector<RootState, MetricState>(
    (state) => state.metricsList
  );

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const classes = useStyles();
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(appReducer.actionCreators.fetchMetrics());
  }, []);
```

Here the definition of fetchMetrics:

```
   export function fetchMetrics() {
      const action = {
        type: ACTION_TYPES.FETCH_METRICS,
         payload: []
       };
      return fetchMetricsCall(action);
    }
    const fetchMetricsCall = (action) => async (dispatch) => {
      try {
        const res = await axios.get("/api/foo");
        dispatch({
          type: action.type,
          payload: res.data //contains the data to be passed to reducer
        });
      } catch (e) {
        dispatch({
          type: ACTION_TYPES.FAILURE,
          payload: console.log(e) //TODO: fix return type
        });
      }
    };
    
    export default {
      fetchMetrics
    };
```

On index.js I create the state and connect the provider

```
const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    applyMiddleware(...middleware)
)

const App = () => {

  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact component={Dashboard} />
        <Route component={NoMatchRoute} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
};
```

And this is my reducer:

```
const initialState: MetricState = {
  metrics: []
};

const fetchMetrics = (
  state = initialState,
  action: MetricAction
): MetricState => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ACTION_TYPES.FETCH_METRICS:
      return {
        ...state,
        metrics: action.payload
      };
    case ACTION_TYPES.CHOOSE_METRIC:
      return {
        ...state,
        metrics: action.payload
      };
    default:
      return {
        ...state
      };
  }
};

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  fetchMetrics
});

export default rootReducer;
```

I just can't make it work. I have already read lots of Stack Overflow questions and tutorials and I just cannot find my error. On the image it's possible to see that the data is fetched from the real API but do not show on the screen.

[image]

Comment: You haven't connected the store to the React tree - add the [Provider](https://react-redux.js.org/api/provider).

Comment: Thank you but actually I did on index.js, no?  <Provider store={store}>

Comment: You've created the store, but the `App` doesn't have the Provider.

Comment: But I did the same as on the documentation link that you have sent: <Provider store={store}>
      <React.StrictMode>
        <App />
      </React.StrictMode>,
    </Provider>,

Comment: You might have did, but it doesn't appear in the question here.

Comment: Its on the codesandbox, I will edit the question to add this on plain text too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like `state.metricsList` actually exists inside the state, and inside the `Dashboard` component is `(state) => state.metricsList`. Your state only has `fetchMetrics.metrics` (`combineReducer` is going to add object onto the state with the key of the reducer's name)

So right now, the structure of your state looks like this:

```
state: { 
  fetchMetrics: { 
    metrics: [] 
  }
}
```

I think the main two things you need to change are:

metrics.ts

```
export type RootState = {
  fetchMetrics: MetricState;
};
```

Dashboard.tsx

```
const catalog = useSelector<RootState, MetricState>(
  (state) => state.fetchMetrics
);
```

In the code sandbox `metrics` is some weird HTML error, let me know if my answer doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you Michael! Indeed this is one of the problems! But now I am fetching the initial state not populated with the new data. This means I am fetching const initialState: MetricState = {
  metrics: []
}; and not the data that the reducer returned

Comment: That's weird, the codesandbox was working when I post the question! I will have a look!

Comment: @CatarinaNogueira I'm not sure why things aren't updating and you're only fetching the initialState. I had to work around a couple things, but I was able to pull updated data from the state: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-listing-forked-18shj?file=/src/components/MetricsList.tsx

Comment: @CatarinaNogueira Could you console.log `res.data` inside your `fetchMetricsCall` and tell me what you get?

Comment: Oh, I am looking at the one you did, it's super nice! I am trying to fix my codesandbox adding your suggestions but I think the server mock is not returning the data because when I do catalog.map I am having problems. I have a question on your code where does it comes the data? Since the server is returning "test" as the name variable and on the screen is showing "one" as the metrics.name variable

Comment: @CatarinaNogueira I just wrote the data into the `fetchMetricsCall`. It's right inside the `dispatch.payload`. Also thank you :)

Comment: I put the console.log and it's returning the payload returned form the server ( It's returning an array of metrics) Ah I see, so if you wrote the data inside fetchMetricsCall maybe the mock of the server is not working on the codesandbox, I will have a look on how you have done

Comment: Michael, I have forked your codesandbox and changed the data to be the same as the data that is returning from the server and It's not working, maybe is a problem on the data mapping. Do you have any suggestion? :)) https://codesandbox.io/s/react-listing-forked-3mr0s

Comment: @CatarinaNogueira I'll try making a quick mockAPI :)))

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231302/discussion-between-michael-hoobler-and-catarina-nogueira).

Comment: Sorry to bother you Michael, but I have discovered that I have an infinite loop calling the api. I have seen that on the deps part of the useEffect I should add the reference to the object I am updating, so I did, but anyway it continues to have the loop. After I read also that calling dispatch() inside udeEffect can be seen as code smell :( . Do you have any opinions on this? :)

Comment: @CatarinaNogueira No worries Catarina. I appreciate you reaching out, I guess I must've done something good and I'm always happy to help, but you should really open a *new* question when you run into a *new* problem! These comments don't really help other people and I like getting the points as they help me my improve my resume and get better job opportunities. I'll check your account later and if no one has answered your question I promise I'll help ;).

Comment: Okk, got it! I will do it :)